# how to resize a HTML browser window with javascript using Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, resize, window

I have a program where I place the element using CSS in % of window height and width. When opened in a monitor with different resolution (only if the ratio height-width is different), the elements are a little bit misplaced. My solution is limit the height of the window when open in Chrome, so I can keep the same ratio. Researching in google, the command ResizeTo looks to be the answer and it looks simple, but I can't make it to work. the command ResizeTo doesn't work at all, what am I doing wrong?

HTML code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>this is an HTML example</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<body style= "width:100%; height:100%; background-color:lightgrey;">
<H1>This is a Header</H1>
<H2>This is a Medium Header</H2>
<P> This is a new paragraph!
<P> <B>This is a new paragraph!</B>
<BR> <B><I>This is a new sentence without a paragraph break, in bold italics.</I></B>
<script src="window.js" ></script>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Javascript:

```
window.resizeTo(1024,900)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to make window.resizeTo(x, y) to work, you need to have opened the window using window.open(...) with size dimentions. Moreover it is not acceptable to resize a browser window, hence Chrome and other browsers have disabled it by default.
Quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo)

> Note: It's not possible to resize a window or tab that wasn’t created by window.open(). It's also not possible to resize when the window has multiple tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I read Parikshith's comment and refined my search.

I found examples to use the window.  Using _self you can use your code in combo with an window.open object.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

[window.onload vs document.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload)